# uboot passes wwrong parameters to the kernel

Tags: linux, kernel, embedded, u-boot

I have an arduino Yun and i want use a rootfs over NFS. This is the command line i'am using :

```
ar7240> setenv bootargs root=/dev/nfs rw nfsroot=192.168.1.1:/home /bou6/srv/nfs/root-ar71xx ip=192.168.1.2:192.168.1.1:192.168.1.1:255.255.255.
0::off;
ar7240> saveenv
Unknown command 'saveenv' - try 'help'
ar7240> printenv        
bootcmd=bootm 0x9fea0000
bootdelay=4
baudrate=115200
ethaddr=0xb4:0x21:0x8a:0x00:0x00:0x10
ipaddr=192.168.1.2
serverip=192.168.1.1
stdin=serial
stdout=serial
stderr=serial
ethact=eth0
bootargs=root=/dev/nfs rw nfsroot=192.168.1.1:/home/user/srv/nfs/rootar71xx ip=192.168.1.2:192.168.1.1:192.168.1.1:255.255.255.0::off

Environment size: 319/65532 bytes
ar7240> bootm 0x9fea0000
```

You can see that saveenv is not recognised by uboot.

When the board reboots this is what i get :

```
[    0.000000] Kernel command line:  board=Yun console=ttyATH0,250000 mtdparts=spi0.0:256k(u-boot)ro,64k(u-boot-env)ro,14656k(rootfs),1280k(ker
nel),64k(nvram),64k(art),15936k@0x50000(firmware) rootfstype=squashfs,jffs2 noinitrd
```

It seems that uboot is passing wrong parameter, actually this is the default command line i have when i bought the board

Should i reflash uboot ?

Comment: Did you try the `help` command like the error message suggested?  That would report the U-Boot commands that were enabled and available.  *"Should i reflash uboot ?"* -- If you don't reconfigure U-Boot to have the commands you need/want (e.g. CONFIG_CMD_SAVEENV), then that won't accomplish much.

Comment: *"It seems that uboot [sic] is passing wrong parameter,"* -- *"Wrong"* is a value judgment.  The Linux kernel can be configured three ways in regards to the command line: (1)   Use bootloader kernel arguments if available; (2) Extend bootloader kernel arguments; (3) Always use the default kernel command string .  Seems like your kernel is not configured for #1 or #2 if you booted the kernel properly.

Comment: Thank you @sawdust, actually by using `help` saveenv is not available, i'am using the uboot shipped on the board, any config till now. Regading rootfs configuration on the Kernel side, This is a VERY GOOD information i don't know this. I will search this option and update the question

Comment: @sawdust, currently i will try to flash a kernel that support the use of bootloader argument, i have few questions to ask before going on: so i'am following this [tuto](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/YunUBootReflash#Reflashing%20kernel), In the reflashing kernel paragraph : the load adress in tftp command is `0x80060000`, then erase of `0x9fEa0000 +0x140000` and finally a copy, my question 1- why we can't use directly a load address `0x9fEa0000` so that the old kernel gets replaced by the new one 2- Can we use another address instead of `0x9fEa0000`, or there is sthing to take in account?

Comment: Apparently your board uses NOR flash, which is XIP (execute in place) capable.  (1) the transfer uses a RAM buffer, rather than write directly to NOR flash.  Not sure why, but it's safer if transfer fails for any reason.  NOR writes are also slow. (2) Not a good idea to change this address unless you know the ramifications.  I'm not familiar with your board, so I can't offer specific advice.